# Regular expression to check us dollar and german currency format

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to find a piece of regex to match a currency value.

if the price is 1000 in USD
then need to validate in the format 1,000.00
But in the case of German it is opposite
like 1.000,00
I need to validate the entered amount is in usd format or german format
also need to save the value in to db by removing both comma and dot like 1000.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^((\d{1,3}\,)*\d{3}|\d{1,3})\.\d{2}$|^((\d{1,3}\.)*\d{3}|\d{1,3})\,\d{2}$/
```

It will match

```
20.00
1,000.00
1.000,00
1.000.000.000,00
1,000,000,000.00
```

but not

```
1,000,000,00.00
,000,000,00.00
100000000.00
1,000,000,000,00
```

etc.

Comment: Thank u @pajaja I need to replace the entered value format for saving in db for ex: 1,000.00 to 1000.00 in the case of usD and for EUr 1.000,00 to 1000.00.How to replace it?

Comment: Hi @pajaja the user need to enter currency without decimal. Then how to change above reg expression for ex:1,000 or 1.000